# Android Foreground Location Service stops after some time

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, location, foreground-service

Im using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android-o-androidplaylocation-locupdfgservice/) code to get location updates for my Xamarin Android app. I have 2 questions.

1. How to make this foreground service to run forever? I've tried to change `return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;` to `return StartCommandResult.Sticky;` and remove anything from `OnDestroy()` method, but OS seems to be unable to recreate service after it was killed or crashed. So, it runs about a half day only, even i've added app to my battery optimization exclude list. How to make it run forever?
2. How to properly start service from boot?
   Here is what i've tried. Added following to `MainActivity.cs`

```
            [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
            public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
            {
                public Context Context { get; set; }
                public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {
                    var stepServiceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(LocationUpdatesService));
                    stepServiceIntent.PutExtra("StartedFromBoot", true);
                    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
                    {
                        context.StartForegroundService(stepServiceIntent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.StartService(stepServiceIntent);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Edited `LocationUpdatesService.cs`

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Log.Info(Tag, "Service started");
            var startedFromNotification = intent.GetBooleanExtra(ExtraStartedFromNotification, false);

            var startedFromBoot = intent.GetBooleanExtra("StartedFromBoot", false);

            if (startedFromBoot)
            {
                
                //Preferences.Set("LocationUpdates", true);
                
                StartForeground(NotificationId, StartNotification("",""));
                Preferences.Set("foreground", true);

                try
                {
                    FusedLocationClient.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest, LocationCallback, Looper.MyLooper());
                }
                catch (SecurityException unlikely)
                {
                    Preferences.Set("LocationUpdates", false);
                    Log.Error(Tag, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
                }
            }
            if (startedFromNotification)
            {
                RemoveLocationUpdates();
                StopSelf();
            }
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
```

I got only single location update that way right from boot. After that single update Im geting "Unknown Location" so service doesnt run continuously. So, how to properly start that service from boot to make it run continuously?

Maybe there will be a single solution for both questions, so if there is a way to start fully functional service from boot, then system could recreate it with Sticky flag and run forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the foreground service will keep running when the phone is on. But you can also use the `PowerManager.WakeLock`  to make sure your app always keep alive even the device is sleep.

You can check this case:[Xamarin wakelock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840226/xamarin-wakelock)

In addition, it seems that you want to get the user's location cyclically. So you can run a timed task in the foreground service. There are many ways to do that. Such as:

- JobScheduler
- AlarmManager
- WorkManager
- ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

You can check this case:[Xamarin Android - Periodic task execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70565884/xamarin-android-periodic-task-execution)

Comment: Thanks! But its not a solutions in my case. That service meant to be running continuously with location updates. Link for original source in first message. The problem is i cant run service separately (for example, from boot) and make it work continuously as it should work (it can get only single update with code i edited above). Of course i can use timed task to run service once and get single update, but its not the way i looking for,, because that service should work always and get periodical updates itself. WakeLock is also partial solution, cause in case of crash OS cant recreate service

Comment: But you just call `FusedLocationClient.RequestLocationUpdates` once in the service, so you will just get location only once. In addition, what does the OS crash mean?  Do you want the foreground service restart even it didn't call the ondestory method?@ibit

Comment: Thanks for answer again! https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android-o-androidplaylocation-locupdfgservice/ please check the original source code. I cant understand which way `FusedLocationClient.RequestLocationUpdates` is getting periodical updates and still work continuously when its running from main app or when foreground service is started from main app (when on pause). So how should i rewrite my code to make it work from boot same way as in app? I also have override for ondestroy method (as in source), but i've deleted code inside, could it be also problem?

Comment: I had read the code and find that it update the location by the button clicked event in the  main activity. In addition, it is not about the ondestroy method.@ibit